# Create a new field with ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

So here the params is a hash, and I would like to concatenate all of the keys and store it to a new field, how can I achieve that? I found that is it possible to use inline ruby code in the configuration file but, I have no idea how to assign the return value of the concat.

```
grok { match => { "request" => [ "url", "%{URIPATH:url_path}%{URIPARAM:url_params}?" ]} }
  urldecode{ field => "url_path" }
  mutate { gsub =>  ["url_params","\?","" ] }
  kv {
    field_split => "&"
    source => "url_params"
    target => "params"
  }
  urldecode{ field => "params" }

  ruby {
    code => 'pattern= params.keys.join(",")'
    #Pattern should be the new field that contains the key, separated by comma
  }
```

Expected result should be:

pattern = "param1,param2,param3 ... and so on"

Comment: You can use `event.set` to add a new field to the logstash event. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/event-api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
event.set('field_name', field_value)
```